# Switching from vue-resource to axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vue-resource

With vue-resource, we could set the root url in `main.js` like so:

```
Vue.http.options.root = 'http://localhost:3000/api'
```

I tried replacing that with:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/api';
Vue.prototype.$http = axios
```

However, now my post calls don't work as expected, and `Vue.http.post` throws an error.

How is this achieved?

Comment: Do not use absolute url path in instance method, you should use relative url

Answer (score 6):

With axios, one can create another instance [having a custom config](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/blob/master/README.md)

```
var my_axios = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000/api',
});
```

From here one can use `my_axios` for operations. You could prototype the custom axios instance into Vue:

```
Vue.prototype.$http = my_axios
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const HTTP = axios.create({
  baseURL: `http://localhost:3000/api/`,
  headers: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer {token}'
  }
})
```

You could now use HTTP like so

```
<script>
import {HTTP} from './http-common';

export default {
  data: () => ({
    posts: [],
    errors: []
  }),

  created() {
    HTTP.get(`posts`)
    .then(response => {
      this.posts = response.data
    })
    .catch(e => {
      this.errors.push(e)
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: If you’d like to access this.$http like in vue-resource, you can just set Vue.prototype.$http = axios.